# Custom security voter issue Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I think I´ve followed all the steps to create a voter to allow users edit only the objects that they created.

1) app / config / services.yml

```
wars.profesorbundle.security.ownervoter :
    class: Wars\ProfesorBundle\Security\OwnerVoter
```

2) OwnerVoter.php

```php
<?php

namespace Wars\ProfesorBundle\Security ;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface ;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface ;

class OwnerVoter  implements VoterInterface
{
    public function supportsAttribute($attribute )
    {
        return 'ROLE_EDITAR_MENSAJE' == $attribute;
    }

    public function supportsClass( $class )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        $vote = VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute ) {

            if (false === $this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
                continue;
            }

            $user = $token->getUser();
            $vote = VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;

            / / Check that the message being edited was published by the same teacher
            if ($object->getProfesor()->getId() === $user->getId()) {
                $vote = VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED ;
            }
        }

        return $vote;
    }
}
```

I don´t know where is the error because I always get a deny exception:

```php
if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_EDITAR_MENSAJE', $panel))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in app/config/config.yml. I forgot to import app/config/services.yml:

*// config.yml*

imports:

**- { services.yml }**